# Is it possible to transfer small HTTP packets over UDP?

Tags: performance, http, udp

For small size JSON requests, I think it would be more efficient to transfer in one UDP diagram, no need to initialize a TCP connection.

If someone have already measured the latency and performance gain, I'd like to know that very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But all browsers will send http over tcp, so if you want to have a udp based "http" you have to write your own web-server and web-client.

In addition you should know that http is strongly dependent on maintain the integrity of the transfer, and if you do not send requests periodically - you must use tсp.

small size and a good network does not guarantee the correct transmission